# Openpgp.js can't decrypt pgp message

Tags: javascript, angular, encryption, openpgp, openpgp.js

I'm using openpgp.js version 2.2.1.

So I've managed to encrypt a message just fine

```
const options = {
    data: voteObject.option,       // input as Message object
    publicKeys: (pgp.key.readArmored(pubkey)).keys, // for encryption
};

pgp.encrypt(options).then(function(ciphertext) {
    console.log(ciphertext.data);
});
```

This logs the encrypted message. The problem I'm now having is that I can't decrypt it. I'm at a complete loss at this point and to be honest I've tried everything to the point I don't know what I'm doing anymore. I know this isn't much to work with but I don't really have anything else to give.

Any suggestions at all would be a huge help!

Comment: I used crypto-js for encrypt and decrypt. If you want that solution I am ready to help you.

Comment: What exactly does not work? Do you get any error message? And what's the value of `options` you pass into `encrypt()`?

Comment: @pschild options contains the string I want to encrypt and a pgp public key, when I try to decrypt I pass the following options: the encrypted message, private key and passphrase. I then get this error:

    ```Error decrypting message: No symmetrically encrypted session key packet found.```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are mixing up the `passphrase` for a key and the `password` for "simply" encrypting a string.
Usually, in PGP a sender is *encrypting* a message with the receiver's *public key*. The receiver of the message can then *decrypt his private key* with his *secret passphrase* and with the resulting *decrpyted private key* he can *decrypt the message*.

I added a working example below:

**Encryption**

```
const receiverPublicKey = ...;

let publicKeys = (await openpgp.key.readArmored(receiverPublicKey)).keys;
let options = {
    data: 'Hello, World!',
    publicKeys: publicKeys
};

return openpgp.encrypt(options)
    .then((encryptedMessageObject) => {
        return encryptedMessageObject.data; // -----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE----- ... wcBMA0rHUQJA4dCdAQg...
    });
```

**Decryption**

```
const receiverPrivateKey = ...;
const receiverPassphrase = 'secret';
const encryptedMessage = '-----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE----- ... wcBMA0rHUQJA4dCdAQg...';

let privKeyObj = (await openpgp.key.readArmored(receiverPrivateKey)).keys[0];
await privKeyObj.decrypt(receiverPassphrase);

let options = {
    message: await openpgp.message.readArmored(encryptedMessage),
    privateKey: privKeyObj
};

return openpgp.decrypt(options)
    .then((plaintextObject) => {
        return plaintextObject.data; // Hello, World!
    });
```

This is the usual process of using PGP with one sender and one receiver (note that the `signing` of the message and `checking the signature` is missing).

Now there's also `password` in the decrypt `options`.
For that, see the example from the docs:

```
var options, encrypted;

options = {
    data: 'Hello, World!',      // input as String
    passwords: ['secret stuff'] // multiple passwords possible
};

openpgp.encrypt(options).then(function(ciphertext) {
    encrypted = ciphertext.data; // '-----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE ... END PGP MESSAGE-----'
});
options = {
    message: openpgp.message.readArmored(encrypted), // parse armored message
    password: 'secret stuff'                         // decrypt with password
};

openpgp.decrypt(options).then(function(plaintext) {
    return plaintext.data; // 'Hello, World!'
});
```

In this case, a `password` is used to encrypt and decrypt a message - no public or private key at all.

I hope that helps!